# Purpose of returning HTML as a Node response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

What is the point of returning HTML as a response from a Node.js server?

I understand templating engines like Pug allow you to generate dynamic HTML using variables.

What I don't understand is why you wouldn't simply return JSON as a response, then use what is returned to render something based on that. I use React for example, so I could render render some JSX dynamically instead

Comment: Isn't it the "SSR" ?

Comment: Why would you want to run a complex application in a browser when you could just as easily render the full HTML serverside?

Comment: and interactions ?